# Asp.net Webapi - Token Based Authentication and External Authentication Providers issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have been digging around to find the right solution for my problem, I have an asp.net Webapi and I send a **POST** request to `/token` with username and password (with `grant_type=password`) to get the token

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:00000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypassword
```

The problem is if the user is signed up using External Authentication Providers such as Google, how will my POST request to `/token` look like in the following RestSharp Code (or postman for example)?

```
public static bool ClaimAuthentication_API(LoginViewModel UserLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient( KeyVault.Environmental_Variables_Application.API_CON + "/token");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");               
                request.AddParameter("undefined", "grant_type=password&username=" + UserLogin.Email + "&password=" + UserLogin.Password, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                string JSONResponse = response.Content.ToString();
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(JSONResponse);
                string AUTH_TOKEN = data.access_token
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In this case, when user logs-in using Google, I don't have `LoginViewModel` which carries the password which I send to `/token` because of the `ExternalLoginCallback` looks like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }


            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:                    
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:

                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email, FullName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName, ProfileImage = profilePicURL});
            }
        }
```

How do I send a POST request to `/token` when using  `ExternalLogin' such as Google.